# How does point cap affect tag badge progress?

Tags: support

If I get point capped and have four up-votes on `[apex]` posts that don't give me any reputation, do they still count towards my tag badge? Never thought I would wonder about something like that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I can safely conclude that each up vote still counts as a point towards badge progress, even if it does not contribute to reputation. I had a question tagged with `[case]` recently get 4 votes that did not contribute rep due to the cap, but each vote made towards that tag counts as a point for badge progress. Just needed to see this situation in effect with a smaller tag. It's a lot easier to count up 17 votes than to track down the answer for 500+.